# Spring Boot security form login and Oauth2 resource server

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot and I want my app to host Oauth2 resource server for accessing my api endpoints on the same server. I also need to have a web interface with secured pages via form login.

For example I have api endpoints /api/v1/** where requests can only be made via having a token from my oauth2 resource server.

Additionally there are endpoints like /account/** where user needs to be logged in via form.

All of this needs to be in one Spring Boot instance for now.

My WebSecurityConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/account/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
}
```

And in my Oauth2SecurityConfig I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/me/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

The problem is, oauth2 config seems to override the first configuration and all my webpage resources are exposed without asking username password in form login. And if I try accessing my api endpoints I get the expected oauth error response.

Do I need to have them both in one overriden method? Do I need to have 2 instances of HttpSecurity? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same situation. Finally got a solution for this. You just need to make the use of @Order annotation.

Add this to your WebSecurityConfig class

```
  @Order(1)
```

And add this to your ResourceServerConfiguration  class

```
  @Order(2)
```

Comment: Why I using spring boot the `/api/v1/me/**` can access by every body?

Answer (score 0):

To secure all your resources you would have to add
`.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`. Did you mean that your "/account/**" resource is exposed?

Those two HttpSecurity objects are not the same object. That being said you don't need to have both of them configured, but each one of them serves different purpose. (I have both of them configured in my project and it's working fine)

I would start by reviewing your expectations for this as I am not sure whether it is feasible to have a part of your server protected by OAuth and another part by another authentication mechanism (Form login). Both would be considered .authenticated(). You could manage the access by roles and oauth scopes, but then you would have to also provide both login/logout mechanisms by different filters and maybe another filter to provide persisting of both authentications when navigating through your server. Seems to me like a lot of not so standard work and I would think about different solutions.